# Potentially dangerous Request.Path & illegal characters in path

Tags: security, redirect, urls, url-rewrite

I am trying to fix this "**Potentially dangerous Request.Path**" issue when URL contains characters like these `- &, <, >, !`
Basically, I need to redirect the page to 404.

Ex:

```
https://<domain>/test-path/**&**
https://<domain>/test-path/**<**
```

All the above URL formats should redirect to the 404 page.

This is my **httpRuntime** configuration in web.config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="10240000" executionTimeout="110" enableKernelOutputCache="false" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="false"
  requestValidationMode="4.0" enableVersionHeader="false" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
  requestValidationType="Sitecore.Web.RequestValidators.SitecoreBackendRequestValidator, Sitecore.Kernel" maxUrlLength="2083"/>
```

I added this **requestPathInvalidCharacters**="" to the `httpRuntime`, now after this addition if the URL contains `&`, then it redirects to 404 which is what I wanted, but if I browse the URL with other characters like `<`, `>`, then I get "**Illegal characters in path.**" issue.
How to handle this, like how can I redirect the page to 404 for all those invalid characters (not just for `&`).

`Note:` I tried to add this also `requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?"` but with this, there is no impact, I still get "Potentially dangerous Request.Path" for all the invalid characters. Appreciate any help.

I am using Sitecore 10

Thanks, Sharath

Comment: Did you check this? - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22056/message-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client